# onPressed call executes 2 functions instead of one

Tags: flutter, dart

I call a function `signInModeIsEmail()` in the onPressed of my elevated button. It executes but, the issue is that it also runs a second function `signInModeIsGoogle()`, reversing the boolean state.

These functions are in my ViewModel class:

```
/*Profile Image and Display Name*/

  bool googleSignIn = false;
  String defaultImgURL =
      'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fd/14/a4/fd14a484f8e558209f0c2a94bc36b855.png';

  Future getCurrentUser() async {
    return _firebaseAuthenticationService.currentUser;
  }

  bool signInModeIsGoogle() {
    googleSignIn = true;
    print('This is also executing. This should not be');

    return googleSignIn;
  }

  bool signInModeIsEmail() {
    googleSignIn = false;
    print('Either this or the next should run but not both');
    return googleSignIn;
  }

  imageURL() {
    if (_firebaseAuthenticationService.currentUser != null) {
      if (signInModeIsGoogle() == true) {
        print('Should provide Google profile image');
        // return NetworkImage(
        //     _firebaseAuthenticationService.currentUser!.photoURL!);
      } else {
        print('Should provide default image');
        // return NetworkImage(defaultImgURL);
      }
    }
  }
```

I call the function here:

```
Container(
                          child: ConstrainedBox(
                            constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(
                                width: 370, height: 85),
                            child: model.isBusy
                                ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                                : ElevatedButton(
                                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                      primary: Colors.green,
                                      onPrimary: Colors.white,
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      model.loggingUser(
                                          email: _emailController.text,
                                          password:
                                              _passwordController.text);
                                      model.signInModeIsEmail();
                                    },
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Sign in',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                    )),
                          ),
                        ),
```

`Would anyone please point me to the reason this is happening?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, of course.
This:

```
  imageURL() {
    if (_firebaseAuthenticationService.currentUser != null) {
      if (signInModeIsGoogle() == true) {
        print('Should provide Google profile image');
        // return NetworkImage(
        //     _firebaseAuthenticationService.currentUser!.photoURL!);
      } else {
        print('Should provide default image');
        // return NetworkImage(defaultImgURL);
      }
    }
  }
```

Should be something like this:

```
  imageURL() {
    if (_firebaseAuthenticationService.currentUser != null) {
      if (googleSignIn) {
        print('Should provide Google profile image');
        // return NetworkImage(
        //     _firebaseAuthenticationService.currentUser!.photoURL!);
      } else {
        print('Should provide default image');
        // return NetworkImage(defaultImgURL);
      }
    }
  }
```

Why? Because this `if (signInModeIsGoogle() == true) {` statement
makes `isGoogleSignIn` true and so this is always `true`.
Hence it is always executed.

Comment: Thanks for your response but unfortunately, this isn't correct. The same error persists and I'm not surprised bcos "==" does not mean assignment. If it was single "=" then you'd be correct. Result in the console:
...I/flutter ( 7319): Either this or the next should run but not both...
...I/flutter ( 7319): This is also executing. This should not be
I/flutter ( 7319): Should provide Google profile image...

Comment: Yes, of course it does not eman assignment, but when you call the function, you set googleSignIn = true and return googleSignIn, therefore that is true. ... YOu should be surprised that you don't see that. :D

Comment: Oh yes! I see my error now. Thanks a lot. checking the function itself executes it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey @muzzletov, this now makes the returned value always false (or whatever it is set to at initialization).

Comment: But isn't that the point? If i have a google account, i click login with google. If not, I click on w/e account option I can log in to with. So, clicking/providing my email should be setting it then. One option: if (mail_address.endsWith("gmail.com")) googleSignIn = true;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233366/discussion-between-william-chidube-and-muzzletov).